# How do I find Vs in this circuit with a 2:1 ideal transformer?

Tags: circuit-analysis, transformer, kirchhoffs-laws

[image: The circuit I'm trying to solve]

How do I find Vs given that V0(to the left) is 10L30degrees? I started by finding that the current on the 10 ohm resistor is 1L30 degrees, and then using kirchoff's law, the current on the tranformer is 4,2L-82 degrees, satisfying:

I = 1 L 30

V0 = I * (j4) + (I - cap_I) * (-5j)

I_on_trans = - I_on_cap + I

I think I messed up at some point.

Comment: You need to work out the transformer secondary voltage, and then you can find the primary voltage and current. Note the dots on the transformer.

Comment: What does "1L30 degrees" mean in proper/normal degrees? Why do you say V0 is to the left?